# Do one dimensional SHMs follow a specific pattern when it comes to their displacements with respect to time?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

I was looking at different kinds of SHMs on $x$-axis and I was wondering if the situations of positions of the particle at different times are similar for different SHMs as the most general SHM (the one in which particle starts from the origin at $t=0 $) I have attached an image to make this more clear (it's just to describe what I mean by 'different SHMs'.

NOTE: these obviously aren't 'different' SHMs the only difference is when and where they start. But the mean position remains the Origin.

[image: FIGURE]

---

As we know for the SHM in which particle starts from the origin at t=0 towards positive x, it's positions are quite symmetrically determined at different times.
That is, at $t=\frac{T}{4}$ , the particle will be  at $+A$ where A is the amplitude and T is the time period.
At $t=\frac{T}{2}$, the particle will again be at the origin moving towards negative x.
At $t=\frac{3T}{4}$ the particle will be at $-A$
and finally at $t=T$ the particle will again be at origin completing 1 cycle.

---

Now my question is will this be the same for the 'other SHMs'? That is, if we consider the first image,
will this particle's displacement be $-A/2$ at $t=T/4$ ? and would it again follow some symmetrical displacement at these specific times?
Would the time period of this even be T?

---

NOTE: In all the cases we are taking here, the mean position is origin.
I know I might be missing out on a lot of basic points but I'm really confused and need some clear explanation about this. Please explain this on the basis of the first image only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the answer to your question is: no.

You seem to be suggesting that the body might cover equal distances in equal time intervals from whatever point in its cycle we start our time interval (or at least that it covers distances of $A$ if we start a time interval of $T/4$ not just at $x=A,\ x=0,\ \text{or}\ x=-A$ but also at certain other points).

Everything is contained in the equation
$$x= A\ \cos \left(\frac{2\pi}{T}t + \epsilon\right).$$
If we agree to call $t=0$ when the body has its maximum $x$-wise displacement, $A$, we can put $\epsilon =0$.

For $x=\frac A2$ we find that the smallest positive value of $t$ is $t=\frac16 T$.

For $x=-\frac A2$ we find that the smallest positive value of $t$ is $t=\frac13 T$.

So the time interval for the body to go from $x=\frac A2$ to $x=-\frac A2$ is $\frac13 T-\frac16 T=\frac16T.$

The reason why this is less than $\frac 14 T$ is that, for a body doing shm, the nearer the body is to its equilibrium position, the faster it moves. The relationship between $x$ and $t$ is non-linear.

Comment: Alright... so we can see that kind of symmetry only in the initial case i was talking about right? like... I'm not saying that the particle covers equal distances in specific intervals. I'm just saying that we observe that after $\frac{T}{4}$ we see it at +A and so on... But we cant apply this to other SHMs starting from some other position right? That is, the displacements won't be specifically defined.

Comment: Also... what about the time period? Would the time period of the **First picture** also be T? That is, where would we observe that particle at time t=T? would it be at the origin or at $+\frac{A}{2}$

Comment: (a) "Would the time period of the First picture also be T?" I'm not sure what you mean; the time period, $T$, is the time for one cycle, from whatever point in the cycle you start. (b) I'm afraid that I find your diagrams hard to understand. For example, you say that the second diagram is for $t=T/8$, yet a time longer than $T/6$ has elapsed since the first diagram ($t=0$), judging by the change in the position of P. (c) I believe that the answers to all your questions are contained in the equation that I quoted in my answer. I recommend that you use it.

Comment: All the diagrams are completely separate and are not related to each other at all. The first diagram depicts an SHM in which the particle begins(t=0) its motion at a displacement of A/2 , the 2nd diagram depicts an SHM in which a particle has its displacement = -A/2  at $t=T/8$ and so on...

Comment: I see. Thank you. So perhaps the answer to your question is simply that the particle in the first diagram will *not* be at $x=-A/2$ at time $T/4$, for the reason that I've explained$.

Comment: Actually, in the problem that I was attempting, I was asked to figure out equations of motion of each of the four SHMs shown in the diagrams. While trying to do that, a friend suggested to me that to check if the equation depicts a particular SHM, we must put the values of time t= T/4, T/2, 3T/4 and T ; and check if it is following some fixed displacements just like it does in the basic SHM about which I mentioned just below the diagrams attached.

Comment: Good luck with determining the equations.